# DirectManipulation ScrollTo functionality

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, direct-composition

I am writing a Win32 application (C++) using **DirectComposition** and **DirectManipulation**. I have sucessfully created a my own Scroll View control by setting viewport and content visuals.

It all works nicely, yet I cannot seem to figure out how to programmatically move the content in the viewport. I would like to create `ScrollTo` behavior where you can bring some content into view.

I've been fiddling around with `SyncContentTransform` but it doesn’t seem to do anything. Do I need to call some other function to commit the sync? Documentation and examples barely exist, I am hoping someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out myself. You should use the `ZoomToRect` method on the viewport object to scroll the content programmatically. I was ignoring this method because it stated "Zoom". Doh.

Here is a link to the function:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/directmanipulation/nf-directmanipulation-idirectmanipulationviewport-zoomtorect

Comment: Hey , i am also struggling with direct manipulation when using in conjunction with direct composition. Can we create IDCompositionSurface greater than that of viewport? For direct manipulation to handle automatically without need for redrawing